# How to split a Polyhedron mesh into a set of diferent Polyhedron having signed faces?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, mesh, cgal

So [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_segmentation/index.html#Chapter_3D_SurfaceSegmentation) we have a Polyhedron mesh with signed faces. But how to put that signed faces into a new Polyhedron mesh? To smplify: say we loaded a 100 faces mesh, we want to pick 50 random faces from it and put them into a new mesh. How one can do it in CGAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the following undocumented function in `CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/connected_components.h`:

```
CGAL::internal::corefinement::extract_connected_components(
  const Polyhedron& P,
  const Adjacency_criterium& adjacent,
  Output_iterator out);
```

Adjacency_criterium is a function object like the following:

```
struct AC_example{
  bool
  operator()(Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle h) const
  {
    bool incident_faces_in_the_same_component = .... ;
    return incident_faces_in_the_same_component;
  }
};
```

It must return true for all but the patch border halfedges.

`Output_iterator` is an output iterator of Polyhedron

In CGAL 4.10, the function moved into `CGAL/internal/corefinemnt/connected_components.h`. A nicer and more generic function is on its way and should be published in an upcoming release.

Comment: Great! Could you please provide minimal usage example? And also provide a reference to what a "patch border half-edges" means in terms of a 3D mesh?

Comment: What can be in `Output_iterator out`? A `Polyhedron` has: `faces_begin`, `halfedges_begin`, `planes_begin`, `points_begin` - I see no general `output_begin` iterator what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your initial question. What I understood was that you wanted to create one polyhedron per segment in a model. In that context, the [output iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) is here to collect the polyhedra and the patch border halfedges are halfedges that are between two faces from different segments.